# Map XML data from different XML Schema

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, altova

We've an XML contains data. We need to extract data from it and move it in to a different XML. Both XMLs are different in structure.

We have Altova and we want to do this job by using it. Any solution on this; which Altova tool will be best for this job and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `XSL Transformation` which in itself is again a XML document that describes how to create the new XML from the old XML.

Check out this [W3Schools section](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) on learning XSLT for that.

In terms of the Altova tools - you could either use the MapForce data mapper (which sounds like that you're looking for), or alternatively the StyleVision tool to create and maintain the XSLT files. Try MapForce first - sounds like a good fit.

Marc

Comment: Thanks marc. Do you know any good tutorial on how to map two xml schema and generate xslt?

Comment: I've tried MapForce and generate a "C#" from it. It generated XSLT and a set of C# project files. At the moment, couldn't completely understand what it did :) Doing some more excerise and looking into ALTOVA help. Any tutorial you would suggest to start it over?

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is the best tool for the job. Beware, though, it's a rather difficult concept to grasp unless you're of a declarative frame of mind.

I wouldn't normally recommend books over online docs, but in this case I would. O'Reilly does two very good books on XSLT (including the Cookbook) that I can highly recommend.

Comment: Sorry skaffman. Perhaps, I didn't explain myself well. I am not completely new to xml/xsl is just matter of time. I worked on xsl a long-time ago. I need to know how I can move data from a XML to another XML and generate a XSLT using ALTOVA? Thanks.